# Which Android-x86 download to choose? (i686, x86_64, k49)?

Tags: installation, android, android-x86

On the Android-x86 [download page](https://osdn.net/projects/android-x86/releases/71931), the following are listed. What is the difference between these? And which one to download to install on, for e.g., an Intel-based PC (i5)? Thank you very much.

```
android-x86-9.0-rc2.i686.rpm 
android-x86-9.0-rc2.iso 
android-x86-9.0-rc2.x86_64.rpm 
android-x86_64-9.0-rc2-k49.iso 
android-x86_64-9.0-rc2.iso
```

Comment: Technically all of those files are compatible with your device.

Answer (score 10):

Naming: (android-x86)-(android_version)-(release_version)_(cpu_architecture or Kernel Version).rpm

i686 = 32 Bit

x86_64 = 64 Bit

k49 = Android Kernel 4.9

Comment: What is the kernel version of the non-k49 iso, and how would one decide which kernel version to use?

Comment: @joe Later versions now explain it in the release notes: https://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-7-1-r5.html "Except the images built with kernel 4.9 as before (the first four files), we also provide experimental images built with kernel 4.19 (the last two files) [suffix k419]. If you have newer devices not supported by kernel 4.9, you may try the kernel 4.19 version."

Answer (score 1):

#### What is the difference between these?

> **Released Files**
>
> This release contains five files. You can choose one of these files
> depends on your devices. Most modern devices should be able to run the
> 64-bit ISO. For older devices with legacy BIOS, you may try the 32-bit
> ISO.
>
> - 64-bit ISO:  android-x86_64-9.0-rc2.iso
>
>   sha1sum: af05f7f28c613f6975be519b2fdd6ae4c0482a02
> - 32-bit ISO:  android-x86-9.0-rc2.iso
>
>   sha1sum: 3a94d0886f998c0b0af8d88b2d99dca7d077388f
> - 64-bit rpm:  android-x86-9.0-rc2.x86_64.rpm
>
>   sha1sum: f4c67d8e580903b8ef2034ae442b2945f4a911a8
> - 32-bit rpm:  android-x86-9.0-rc2.i686.rpm
>
>   sha1sum: 8ee0f575cec2e2d468ababd8ec99d70663d9a50f
> - 64-bit ISO with kernel 4.9:  android-x86_64-9.0-rc2-k49.iso
>
>   sha1sum: 4279f5a0a8f37ae340e6fff5f8542352da464bf0
>
>   Recommended for VMware users
>
> To use an ISO file, Linux users could just dump it into a usb drive to
> create a bootable usb stick like:
>
> ```
> dd if=android-x86_64-9.0-rc2.iso of=/dev/sdX
> ```
>
> where `/dev/sdX` is the device name of your usb drive.
>
> Windows users can use the tool [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) to create a
> bootable usb stick.
>
> Please read [this page](https://www.android-x86.org/installhowto.html) about how to install it to the device.
>
> Except the traditional ISO files, we also package android-x86 files
> into a Linux package rpm. It allows Linux users to easily install the
> release into an existing Linux device with a standalone ext4 root
> partition.

Source [Release 9.0-rc2 | Android-x86](https://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-9-0-rc2.html)

Comment: So what is the difference between these? (Other than sha1sum and titles of those?) Thank you very much.

Comment: What is not clear about the answer? There are 32 and 64 bit versions, a version for VMWare users, a Windows version, and ISO and rpm versions ...